# ASP.Net IgnoreRoutes Does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have an svg file as my assets and in routeconfig, I have mentioned the below code

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*svg}", new { svg = @"(.*/)?.svg(/.*)?" });
```

This seem to be working fine with cassini (Visual Studio 2012 Buit-in Deployment Server) but when I deploy it to Azure I get a 404.

Is my IgnoreRoute statement right ? or any other solutions ? all other images, style sheets seems to work ok.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never have to ignore routes for files that physically exist on disk, the routing module will not try to route those requests. You only need to ignore routes to other virtual resources.

Azure web sites do not have a mime type configured for .svg files, at least at the end of last year they didn't. You can configure a mime type for svg in the `<system.webserver>` section of your web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>      
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
</staticContent>
```

The remove is there to prevent errors on servers that already have an entry for .svg. It's an error to add a duplicate fileExtension, but not an error to remove a non-existent extension.

More here: [Configuration Tips For ASP.NET MVC 4 on a Windows Azure Website](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/07/configuration-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-4-on-a-windows.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Phil's Blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) I think what you need is something like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvg}", new {allsvg=@".*\.svg(/.*)?"});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What order are you declaring the routes? It could be that above that one you have default or catch-all a route that actually already handles the request and so your IgnoreRoute never gets hit.